# "Support to do" or "Support doing"

Tags: word-usage

I am writing features for our product, such as:

- Support to repair corrupt Outlook PST file.
- Support to recover message body and subject.

...

Here **Support** is used as a verb instead of noun. It is an abbreviation of "Our tool supports to repair corrupt Outlook PST file".

A similar sample can be found in https://www.winzip.com/en/product/winzip/#features, where there is a feature "**Organize your photos in the cloud**". Here **Organize** is a verb.

However, the Grammarly extension in Chrome will always suggest me to change "Support to do" to "Support doing".

I try to search online, and it seems both are OK. And I see many software use "Support to do" as their feature lists as well.

So, just wonder which one is correct?

Comment: Your product provides *support for* those utilities?

Comment: Or _support with_ doing something?

Comment: _Support_ as a noun works differently from _support_ as a verb. Be clear what you're trying to say. Full sentences instead of short chunks are more valuable in discussing languages.

Comment: @JohnLawler, here support is used as verb.

Comment: You're correct that support **to** do is used more frequently. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=support+doing%2Csupport+to+do&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Comment: @Eden0516, Thank you very much for your information. Also thank you for letting me know such an interesting tool from Google.

Comment: @alancc Yeah, it's really useful when I'm explaining those "should I use A or B" questions. Good to know you like it.

Comment: @Eden0516, Yeah, in the past, I input "Phrase A" or "Phrase B" in Google.com and based on the found results to know the popularity. But the new tool is much more advanced and also shows the trends.

Comment: Can you provide more context on the tool you're describing?  As-is it is difficult to separate what the sentences in question actually mean from what you intend for them to mean.

Comment: You do not need the word support in those sentences.

Answer (score 6):

'Support' can be used as a verb or a noun:

- We support you (verb)
- We give you support (noun)

Your bullet-pointed list of features uses it as a *noun*, and as a native British English speaker with 25 years of experience in IT support I would say the most idiomatic way to state this would be:

- Support *for repairing* corrupt Outlook PST file**s**.
- Support *for recovering* message body and subject.

This is because the support is a permanent feature and presumably can be used more than once, as required. Saying "support to repair **a** file" could sound like you assume they already have a corrupt file and they can only use the feature once.

Comment: Sorry but here I assume support is a verb. It is short for "Our tool supports to repair corrupt files".

Comment: @alancc You've said *supports* just now, not 'support'. See the first two examples in my answer for the difference. I perceive that you are stating a *feature* of your software. A feature would be identified by a noun, or in this case, a noun phrase.

Comment: Thank you. I check other software feature lists such as https://www.winzip.com/en/product/winzip/#features, it can use a phrase such as "Organize your photos in the cloud" where Organize is a verb. So here we do the similar thing, "Support to repair a file" where Support is a verb.

Comment: @alancc no, "Organize your photos" would be equivalent/parallel to "Repair your files," not "Support repairing your files." What your software does is not allowing the user to support repairing files, but rather allowing the user to *repair their files*. If you wish to use "support" in that context, you would use one of the forms in this answer.

Comment: @alancc if I saw one of the formats from your question, I would immediately think that it was translated from a foreign language by non-native English speakers, which is most likely the case with all of the software you found that follows those conventions.

Answer (score 1):

### To answer your specific question:

> However, the Grammarly extension in Chrome will always suggest me to change "Support to do" to "Support doing"...So, just wonder which one is correct?

In your specific case, you should use "supports doing" as shorthand for "this product supports doing".

### However, I think you are overcomplicating your writing.

The following is writing advice.

Looking at the Winzip site you provided as an example, we can see the following list of features:

- More efficient file compression with duplicate file detection
- Organize your photos in the cloud
- Automatically save cloud files
- Experience better Zipx Compression
- Seamless integration with Microsoft Teams
- Access and edit files shared with you by others

Notice that none of them begin with the word "Support".  This is because that word isn't needed and would be redundant.  It would be visual clutter on the webpage as well:

- Supports more efficient file compression with duplicate file detection
- Supports organizing your photos in the cloud
- Supports automatically saving cloud files
- Supports experiencing better Zipx Compression
- Supports seamless integration with Microsoft Teams
- Supports accessing and editing files shared with you by others

Used in this way, "support" could be considered a **[filler word](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/how-we-use-filler-words/)**.  The goal should be for each feature to be fully described in the most concise and clear way possible.  Filler words should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

The word "support" is not the right word to use if you're describing a product. When you're describing something that a product does, "support" is too weak or too vague. You can use it, however, when you describe something that a product tolerates or accommodates, rather than actively does.

For example, while you can say:

> Our product supports repairing corrupt Outlook PST files.

You would typically say (at least in American English):

> Our product repairs corrupt Outlook PST files.  or

> Our product helps you repair corrupt Outlook PST files.

But you might say:

> Our product supports both single- and double-byte languages.

You might also hear support used more often when talking about services rather than products.

Answer (score 0):

**Product support:**

**Our product repairs corrupt Outlook PST file.**
**It recovers the body of messages and message subjects.**